# Calling same function within itself changes argument value unexpectedly

Tags: python

Need some help in understanding why this function return the 'url_path_list' argument when called from within the same function?

When the script hits the part:

```
if count==1:
    download_loop(url_path_list,count)
```

I do not ask the function to return anything yet, the new 'url_path_list' value seems to be returned. The url_path_list argument is returned as 009 for some reason without me asking it to (i think). I have a workaround for this, I just wanted to understand why the code is doing this.

```
import re

def download_loop(url_path_list,count):
    
    sequence_num=re.findall('[0-9]+',url_path_list[count+1])[0]
    num=sequence_num 
    while int(num)<10:
        
        new_path=url_path_list[count+1][:3]+num+url_path_list[count+1][3+2:]
        url_path_list[count+1]=new_path
        print(url_path_list[2],count)
        count+=1
        if count==1:
            download_loop(url_path_list,count)
        count-=1
        print(url_path_list[2],count)
        num=int(num)
        num+=1
        num='0'*(len(sequence_num)-len(str(num))) + str(num)
        
download_loop(['Hello','thi01s','iii01s','a','test'],0)
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, my question is why the two print statements print different values when i think they should be the same.

Comment: Some of your code seem to be missing. What is `download_loop` ?

Comment: What is this code trying to accomplish?  Increase numbers in input-elements up to 9? whatfor ? You print stuff and calculate stuff but never do anything with it

Comment: Hi, the code is part of a bigger script but I've stripped it out because it was giving me some unexpected results. The script is meant to iterate over sequential files i.e.'1,2,3,4,5,etc...' and also folder names so I go into one folder (say 'f1') and iterate over files in 'f1', then move on to folder 'f2' and iterate over the files in 'f2' which is why i'm calling the function within a function. The problem is with the code above, when it finishes with files in folder 'f1' and moves on to folder 'f2' the 'num' value remains at 9 rather than going back to 1.

Comment: Why do you think it's returning `url_path_list`?

Comment: I found that it is because the download_loop function in the if statement is returning a value that I didn't specify (I think) so I would like to understand why its returning that.

Comment: @RoyCohen because the two print statements should return the same thing. The function that is called between the 2 print statements shouldn't return anything surely?
Let me clarify, the first print statement prints a string with 01 inside but then after the if statement is complete, the second print statement is printing a string with 09 rather than 01

Comment: Do you mean "The function that is called between the 2 print statements shouldn't **change** anything surely?"?

Comment: @RoyCohen Yes thats correct, but it is changing the value of 'url_path_list[2] and I don't want it to

Comment: @Hao-Yuan first of all, you should change the quastion because 'return' and 'change' are complitly different things. secondly, have you tried: `download_loop(url_path_list.copy(),count)`? That's not the fastest or the most space efficient sollution but it might work.

Comment: @RoyCohen sure I will change the title, and thank you it worked (although I actually had a way around this in my main code) - the problem is that I don't understand why it wasn't working without making a copy?

Comment: @Hao-Yuan It's because in python, lists are mutable, that means that they can change.When you passed the list as an argument to the function, without making a copy, the variable `url_path_list` refered to the list you passed. And the line `url_path_list[count+1]=new_path` changed that list.

Comment: @RoyCohen yes I am aware of that, its just I didn't realize that it would also change when you put the list into a new function - i.e. I thought that whatever happens inside the function stays only in the function unless I tell the function to return a value.

Comment: @Hao-Yuan As long as there's only one list, all refrences to that list will be the same.

Comment: @RoyCohen Thank you very much for your help :)